# PHP Select Table With Highest Field Value

Tags: php

I have 10 tables in a MySQL database which are all set up with with the fields `id`,`a`, `b`, `c` and `average`. All fields have numerical values and there is a record for each id in every table. How can I return the name of the table which has the highest `average` value for a specific id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to write this out for 10 tables, but here's the essence of it.

UNION 10 derived tables, like this:

```
SELECT id, average, 'Table1' AS TableName FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT id, average, 'Table2' AS TableName FROM Table2
```

With that 10-table union as a subselect, write an outer query that selects TOP 1 TableName, order by average DESC, WHERE id=@desiredId.